# get each function start at second tr

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="table">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>b</td>
  <td>c</td>
  <td>d</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>a2</td>
  <td>b2</td>
  <td>c2</td>
  <td>d2</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td>a3</td>
  <td>b3</td>
  <td>c3</td>
  <td>d3</td>
</tr>
</div>
```

function

```
$('#table').find('td:nth-child(2)').each(function(index, tr) {

});
```

I want to get this function to skip over the 1st `<tr>`, I want it to start at second `<tr>`, but without adding class or anything else. use pure html on the each function. only the table id available.

So the result I want is

**a2, b2, c2, d2, a3, b3, c3, d3.**

Answer (score 4):

Get `td` elements from the second `tr` onwards using [`:nth-child`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) pseudo-class selector.

```
$('#table tr:nth-child(n + 2) td').each(function(index, tr) {

});
```

```js
$('#table tr:nth-child(n + 2) td').each(function(index, tr) {
  console.log($(this).text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
      <td>c2</td>
      <td>d2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a3</td>
      <td>b3</td>
      <td>c3</td>
      <td>d3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `gt()` selector to take all elements after the element at position 0(the first)

```js
$('#table tr:gt(0) td').each(function(index, tr) {
  console.log($(this).text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
      <td>c2</td>
      <td>d2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a3</td>
      <td>b3</td>
      <td>c3</td>
      <td>d3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```